# Results from IMPORTHTML formula in Google Sheets if starts with 0. the 0. is skipped

Tags: google-sheets

I want to obtain in a Google Sheets cell, the value of a cryptocoin at certain date.

So I have, for example, the following url which shows the prices (open, high, low, close) of the Waves criptocurrency at 15th of December: 
[Link](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/Waves/historical-data/?start=20171215&end=20171215)

So with

```
=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/Waves/historical-data/?start=20171215&end=20171215";"table";1);2;2)
```

I am getting the Openning Price from that url. In this case: 13.55

But I don't know why when the resulting value starts by 0 point, it skips that part (the 0 point) . With the following formula:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/Ripple/historical-data/?start=20171215&end=20171215";"table";1);2;2)
```

I am getting 861760 whereas the Opening Price in the url is: 0.861760

I don't know if it has to do with me being from  Spain and here we use 0, (zero comma) and no 0. (0 point) and I must configure something to use the 0. notation or what...

Comment: I tried you formula with spreadsheet settings locale set to Spain and format set to automatic and it works fine. It returns 0,86176.

Comment: I tried changing the locale to other countries and even change the cell format to all type of numbers but I always get 861760...

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting your number formats from Automatic to a custom format like `'0.00000`. If that doesn't work this might...

```
=IF(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/Ripple/historical-data/?start=20171215&end=20171215","table",1),2,2)>1,CONCATENATE("0.",INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/Ripple/historical-data/?start=20171215&end=20171215","table",1),2,2)),INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/Ripple/historical-data/?start=20171215&end=20171215","table",1),2,2))
```

You might need to switch the ">" for "<"

Or perhaps...

```
=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/Ripple/historical-data/?start=20171215&end=20171215","table",1),2,2)*CONCATENATE("0.", REPT(0,len(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/Ripple/historical-data/?start=20171215&end=20171215","table",1),2,2))-1),1)
```

Comment: I always get that the result is > 1, even if it really is lower than 1, the number I obtain is 861760.

Comment: I added another option to my answer. Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `importhtml` already parses the data using the spreadsheet's locale, so there is nothing you can do to restore correct data if it was parsed incorrectly. Information is already corrupted.

What you can do:

1. Change the locale in Spreadsheet Settings to some country which uses dot as decimal separator ([see the list here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/106243)). It's probably best to use the country from where the data comes from.
2. But you probably prefer to work in your familiar locale. In that case, create a new spreadsheet just with `importhtml` that you need, setting its locale as in #1. In your main spreadsheet, use [`importrange`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) to import the data from the new spreadsheet. The data now arrives unharmed, because `importhtml` interpreted it correctly, and `importrange` knows what to do to move data between spreadsheets, even between different locales.